# Navigation Drawer with Bottom navigation drawer

Tags: android-studio, navigation, toggle, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

How to use both Navigation Drawer and Bottom Navigation View  in same screen . i would like to open from the bottom navigation same as it opens when toggle(menu icon ) is clicked in Navigation app bar.

[Not able to open Navigation drawer from bottom navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWWF1.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried.

Comment: did you mean open navigation drawer on bottom menu button click ? if yes the you just put this code on bottom menu button click 
**drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);**

Comment: @Arbaz.in Thank you so much it's working.